# Cannot Find Load Test in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Tags: .net, visual-studio, testing

I've just installed Visual Studio 2010 and want to perform a load test. But when I create a test project, and click add test - there is no option for load test - just the unit tests.

Comment: check this link : http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/07/08/load-testing-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: Nope - just shows you how to use it once it is there.

Comment: Hi, Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall --> Install --> works

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where certain VS 2010 templates weren't appearing.
I fixed it by re-installing VS 2010 SP1.
Got the idea from this SO post: [Test templates missing in visual studio 2010 ultimate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764735/test-templates-missing-in-visual-studio-2010-ultimate)