# Test templates missing in visual studio 2010 ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, coded-ui-tests

Test templates such as Coded-UI testing and Web performance testing are missing.

I originally had visual studio 2010 professsional installed. I upgraded to visual studio 2010 ultimate just so that I wanted to use Coded-UI testing and Web performance testing features.
However, the options seem to be missing. It is as if the upgrade has not made a difference with regards to additional testing templates.

I have a visual studio 2010 ultimate evaluation version installed.

I have checked in Tools > Options > Test tools: but doesn't seem to have anything in here that I can change. Searched online too, everywhere seem to suggest that after VS 2010 Ultimate installed, you should be have the templates to create the additional tests.

If I go to menu, Test > New test > Add new test dialog,
Here I just have "Basic Unit test", "Ordered test", "Unit test", "Unit Test wizard"
Have also tried, Right click the Test project, Add > no option for Coded-UI test here!

Has anyone come across anything like this?

Any advice is appreciated,
Thanks, Fred

**Edit 09:22 GMT 26-05-2012:**

I used the visual studio ultimate web-installer. I double checked the options to select while installation. There is no option specific to testing here. So, selected Visual C# + Visual Web developer + Graphics library

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue when upgrading from VS2010 Professional to VS2010 Ultimate. I think it may have been caused by having already installed SP1 in Professional. I solved it by doing the following:

- Go into Windows **Add/Remove** programs and run a **Repair** against VS2010 (takes a LONG time).
- You might need a reboot, do not skip the reboot if prompted.
- Re-run **VS2010 SP1 setup** and run **Repair** when prompted (takes a LONG time).

That should do the trick! Run up VS2010 and the templates should now be accessible!

Good luck!

Comment: Just re-installing VS 2010 SP1 worked for me, now I can see the templates